# How do I obtain Sleep(0) like behaviour in Linux

Tags: c, linux

On Windows Sleep(0) yields thread control without specifying a minimum time, ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727420/significance-of-sleep0))
But on Linux and POSIX sleep(0) from unistd.h is just ignored.

What's the best way to get Sleep(0) like behaviour in Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [sched_yield](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) from "sched.h", that is created just for what you want to do.

If that doesn't work for whatever reason - try `usleep(1)` - That will yield at least 1 microsecond delay (may be more), which in turn triggers a context switch (if any thread is waiting).

Comment: `nanosleep` provides much higher resolution, not to mention `usleep` was deprecated in POSIX and slated for removal...