# yielding from linux kernel

Tags: linux, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, real-time

I have a real-time thread in Linux (3.4).   Under certain conditions, I want it to relinquish control to other threads with the same priority, even if it hasn't finished using up its current timeslice.  I was thinking of using the following code:

```
if (condition) {
    resched_task();
    cond_resched();
}
```

however, I don't see anyone else in the code doing this, making me think there's some other (better?) way of doing this.  Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [sched_yield()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_yield) function to yield the rest of your time slice, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504405/how-do-i-obtain-sleep0-like-behaviour-in-linux).

> sched_yield() causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU. The thread is moved to the end of the queue for its static priority and a new thread gets to run.

Comment: Thanks.  You wouldn't know the difference between sched_yield() and yield() are would you?

Comment: @John What yield() function are you talking about? I'm not aware of one called simply `yield()`, sorry.

Comment: In core.c (line 5029), there is a function called yield.  On top of the function there is a big warning: `Do not ever use this function, there's a 99% chance you're doing it wrong.`...   It ends up calling sys_sched_yield(), which makes me a bit weary.

Comment: @John Ah, that looks like something internal to the kernel. `sched_yield()` is a POSIX-standard syscall. I'm not a kernel hacker but I would certainly use the POSIX call and respect the warning you found in `core.c` :)

Answer (score 2):

The question sounds like it's asking about kernel programming but the accepted answer is a function user mode API sched_yield().  I think the kernel answer to this question is schedule()

Comment: `schedule()` doesn't put you at the back of the runqueue if the timeslice is not up, meaning that you end up waking up again right away.   `yield()` does push you to the back, allowing the next process to run.   After some analysis, we found that `yield()` was in fact the correct call despite the comment above it.  (note - this only applies to RR runqueues though)

Comment: @John Are you sure schedule() doesn't put it at the end of queue? what's its purpose then. Do we relinquish cpu to get woken up right away?