# Cross platform Sleep function for C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sleep

Is it possible with macros make cross platform Sleep code?
For example

```
#ifdef LINUX
#include <header_for_linux_sleep_function.h>
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <header_for_windows_sleep_function.h>
#endif
...
Sleep(miliseconds);
...
```

Comment: If you don't mind the processor whirring away and have C++11, you can use `<chrono>`.

Comment: Why would you have the processor whirring away? If you have C++11 you can use something like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(n))` which should not consume any CPU.

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk that's an almost worthless description. I doubt there is much "pure C++" code out there, since no compiler in existence can handle "pure C++". For what is worth, C++11 *is not an extension*, it's actually the real "pure C++".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I never realized that existed; I just started with `chrono` yesterday. That saves me a lot of trouble, thanks.

Comment: In my programs, I use `<time.h>`. It's very reliable.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes there is.  What you do is wrap the different system sleeps calls in your own function as well as the include statements like below:

```
#ifdef LINUX
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#endif

void mySleep(int sleepMs)
{
#ifdef LINUX
    usleep(sleepMs * 1000);   // usleep takes sleep time in us (1 millionth of a second)
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
    Sleep(sleepMs);
#endif
}
```

Then your code calls `mySleep` to sleep rather than making direct system calls.

Comment: #ifdef LINUX  int Sleep(int sleepMs) { return usleep(sleepMs * 1000); } #endif

Comment: ya, that would be great, but usleep doesnt stop consuming CPU. For example: while(1) { usleep(1000*1000);/*1sec?*/ cout << 1; } Then after this one sec, output is many of "1" characters.

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk: No, `usleep` does _not_ consume CPU, it stops the process entirely for a while.

Comment: so why output for code above is many of 1 characters instead of just one? I understand that is not related. But how to fix it?

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk: because you made some other mistake.  The code you posted should print one `1` character per second.

Comment: There is no mistake in while(true) codeblock, as u can see there is just sleep and cout, and this code I compiled. Btw. I used usleep(1000) and it work for 1 sec. :)

Comment: Why take an `int` for `mySleep`? Wouldn't an `unsigned int` be a better choice? After all, it's not like you can sleep for negative seconds! :P

Comment: If anyone tries this with MinGW derivative (ie gcc g++) on Windows, there is a problem with the macros.
If you add `-DWINDOWS` to your compilation parameters (like `g++ xx.cpp -DWINDOWS`), the CPU consumption is over.

Comment: Note that "POSIX.1-2001 declares this function obsolete; use `nanosleep(2)` instead. POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of `usleep()`." [source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)

Comment: The macros don't work. See here on how to reliably detect the platform: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor

Answer (score 83):

Yup. But this only works in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and [later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
```

where `ms` is the amount of time you want to sleep in milliseconds.

You can also replace `milliseconds` with `nanoseconds`, `microseconds`, `seconds`, `minutes`, or `hours`. (These are specializations of the type [std::chrono::duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).)

**Update:** In [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14), if you're sleeping for a set amount of time, for instance 100 milliseconds, `std::chrono::milliseconds(100)` can be written as `100ms`. This is due to [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), which were introduced in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11). In [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) the `chrono` library has been extended to include the following user defined literals:

- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h)
- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22min)
- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s)
- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""ms`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22ms)
- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""us`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22us)
- [`std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""ns`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22ns)

Effectively this means that you can write something like this.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
```

Note that, while `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals` provides the least amount of [namespace pollution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236404/what-is-using-namespace-pollution), these operators are also available when `using namespace std::literals`, or `using namespace std::chrono`.

Comment: @ThePirate42 haha thanks. At the time it was posted though, most people were not yet using C++11, so the accepted answer was more generally useful.

Answer (score 29):

shf301 had a good idea, but this way is better:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define Sleep(x) usleep((x)*1000)
#endif
```

Then use like this:

```
Sleep(how_many_milliseconds);
```

Comment: Convenient! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 19):

Get [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/).

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
...
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(milliseconds));
```

Comment: this is now in C++11. `posix_time` is called `chrono` though.

Answer (score 8):

The stock solution is the select() call (requires Winsock). This particular call has exactly the same behavior on Linux and Windows.

```
long value; /* time in microseconds */

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = value / 1000000;
tv.tv_usec = value % 1000000;
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tf);
```

Comment: interesting solution, but I liked your comment on `shf301`'s answer better.

Comment: this doesn't work on Windows, it returns immediately, regardless of the requested timeout

Answer (score 1):

In linux remember that usleep has a limit.
You can't 'sleep' more than 1000 seconds.

I would write like this

```
struct timespec req={0},rem={0};
req.tv_sec=(milisec/1000);
req.tv_nsec=(milisec - req.tv_sec*1000)*1000000;
nanosleep(&req,&rem);
```

Answer (score 1):

since c++ 11 you could just do this.

```
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>
int main(){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));//sleeps for x milliseconds
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(x));//sleeps for x seconds  
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(x));//sleeps for x minutes
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(x));//sleeps for x hours.
  return 0;  
}
```

I don't know why would you want to use messy macros when you can do this, this method is great, cross platform and is included in the c++ standard.