# How to change text while running the console

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete printed characters from command line in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271362/how-to-delete-printed-characters-from-command-line-in-c)

my question is, how do I change text while RUNNING a console window in C++. For example.

If I were to display this.

```
cout<<"0%";
cout<<"25%";
cout<<50%";
cout<<75%";
cout<<"100%";
```

It will make 5 different words. What if I want it to display 0% then 25% withought making a new word, I.E replacing the current 0% with a 25%. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be platform specific, most likely.  But try printing a backspace character, it might work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271362/how-to-delete-printed-characters-from-command-line-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `cout << number << '\r' << flush`.

The `'\r'` means "carriage return" (go to beginning of line", the `flush` means "make sure what I've just printed reaches the output now. Normally output is only printed when a end of line is provided.

Edit: If you have a situation where the length of the output varies, e.g. counting down, you will have to pad the output with sufficient spaces to cover any extra output. For example `cout << setw(3) << number ...` or `cout << number << "      "  ...` would work.

Be aware, however, if your line gets longer than the width of the termina/command windo, it may become messy.

Comment: but if you print "25%" and then "0%", will it show up as "0%%" or will the original "%" disappear?

Comment: Updated my answer to cover that part.

Comment: So basically I need to type: cout<<"10%" << '/r' << flush; cout<<"20%"?

Comment: Yes, but I presume you want to do something more in between?

Comment: If I want to convert the  cout<<"0%";
cout<<"25%";
cout<<50%";
cout<<75%";
cout<<"100%"; Can you give me the code to display it with the replace line?

Comment: What are you asking for? As you wrote, that's what you need to do - I'm just assuming that you want your progress counter to show something progressing, not just go from 0% to 100% in about 1ms and no one ever sees anything other than 100% anyways... But I have been assuming a few things wrong when it comes to beginner programmers, so I guess this could be one of those. Have you actually tried something - and if so, what was the effect? I'm not going to write the code for you - that's not how YOU learn.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't really understand. How do I convert the "0%" for example to the "25%" using your << '/r' << Flush? I assume I'm supposed to write something like cout<< "0%" << '/r' << Flush; cout<<"25%"; ?

Comment: Yes, you need multiple cout statements. Whether that's part of a loop, several individual ones, etc depends on what your intentions are - which is still not clear. The code you have shown above, if you make my modifications, could just be replaced with `cout << "100%";` since there is nothing taking time in between, so it will go very quickly onto the screen.

Comment: Yes, but you can Sleep(1000) in between. I'm just wondering what people use when they want to show a loading bar in the console window, it's usually in percentages.

Comment: Yes, but you show a loading bar BECAUSE you are _DOING_ something!

Comment: I'm not really "doing" anything, I'm just wondering for future reference. Thanks for answering my questions though.

Comment: @user1930233  Do you understand the difference between `/` & `\ `. His answer uses `\r` but you keep referring to it as `/r`?