# Display dynamic value in C++ console application

Tags: c++, multithreading

in was like to do display values of a dynamic integer on console application with out scrolling down the application background.
the integer was passed in to thread by ref.
thread will change the values if the integer.

currently i was doing it like this in the main method/ thread

```
int data;
thread t1((ProCount()),ref(data));
while(true){
cout<<"data :"<<data<<endl;
system("CLS");
}
```

but for CLS command will take lot of processing power is there any other decent way to do it??

Comment: You want to wait for the thread to signal a change before updating the display. A [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is good for that.

Comment: There's no standard c++ way to clear the console. That's OS/Terminal program specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change text while running the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043148/how-to-change-text-while-running-the-console)

Comment: And if your application's interface is complex enough, look into [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), one of the more common ways of creating TUI's

Comment: but i mainly wanted remove the CLS part and stop scrolling the console app..

so that the data will dynamic data integer veritable changes on at the same position of the console panel.. that was the thing i wanted to do

Comment: And what we're telling you is that there isn't a general way to do this (in C/C++). It's console/OS specific. There are many 3rd party libraries that allow creating of Text User Interfaces, like ncurses.

Comment: @gamal "CLS" is a windows command. If you're not concerned with portability and would accept a windows-specific solution, you should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using ncurses:

http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html

It exists for all cmd-line environments (Windows cmd prompts, Linux, MacOS, etc), and it provides a standard C/C++ interface.

ADDENDUM:

If all you want to do is reposition the cursor to re-write a value, you could also use the Windows API [SetConsoleCursorPosition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For example:

```
#include <windows.h> 

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  COORD coord;
  coord.X = x;
  coord.Y = y;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `"\b"` multiple time and add a sleep.

Comment: Relying on `'\b'` for this is pretty shell specific and likely will not produce the desired effect.