# What is the resolution of windows high performance counter?

Tags: c++, windows

This might seem like a really basic question but, When dividing the output of

`QueryPerformanceCounter` with `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, what is the resulting value in, i.e. seconds, milliseconds, microseconds?

I'm asking because I'm porting some code from Windows to Linux and I don't have a windows machine handy to experiment with.  Some googling around provided no concrete answer for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some googling around provided no concrete answer for me.

First Google search result for "QueryPerformanceCounter": the MSDN documentation for [`QueryPerformanceCounter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904.aspx)

Here's what it has to say:

> **Parameters**
>
> *lpPerformanceCount* [out]
>
> Type: **LARGE_INTEGER***
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the
>   current performance-counter value, **in counts**.

First Google search result for "QueryPerformanceFrequency": the MSDN documentation for [`QueryPerformanceFrequency()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905.aspx)

Here's what it has to say:

> **Parameters**
>
> *lpFrequency* [out]
>
> Type: **LARGE_INTEGER***
>
> A pointer to a variable that
>   receives the current performance-counter frequency, **in counts per
>   second**. If the installed hardware does not support a high-resolution
>   performance counter, this parameter can be zero.

The value obtained from `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is in counts. The value obtained from `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` is in counts per second. Using a bit of dimensional analysis:

```
(counts) / (counts/second) = seconds
```

Therefore, the result of dividing the two values is in seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed that part!

Comment: This does not mean, however, that the resulting value of the divide is expressed in whole seconds. The high-performance counter allows you to implement counters with less than seconds precision. Say `QFF()` returns 100, you would be able to call `QFC()` and get a different value up to 100 times a second.

Comment: It's the integer part I was curious about.

Comment: Be-careful using counters if the counter is not counted you will have incorrect results!!! See my answer!

Answer (score 7):

We've updated the documentation for QueryPerformanceCounter, and the comparison between RDTSC and QueryPerformanceCounter accuracy above isn't quite right.  For further information please see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx

Ed Briggs
Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 1):

At least as far as I know, QPF typically depends on one of two sources. At least at one time, most single-processor systems used the processor's time-stamp counter register, accessed via the RDTSC instruction.

Multi-processor systems (and older systems that didn't have a TSC register) normally use the motherboard's on-board 1.024 MHz clock. On a multiprocessor/multicore system, the time-stamp counters of the processors/cores can be out of sync, so the time-stamp counter could give rather meaningless results (including negative time periods).

Answer (score 1):

Even though In silico answered the question, if you're looking for higher timer resolutions, you can use the `rdtsc` assembly instruction. `rdtsc` is about 1000x more accurate than `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` as it uses the CPU clock (as opposed to the motherboard clock). The method would look something like so:

```
void QueryRDTSC(__int64* tick) {
 __asm {
  xor eax, eax
  cpuid
  rdtsc
  mov edi, dword ptr tick
  mov dword ptr [edi], eax
  mov dword ptr [edi+4], edx
 }
}
```

**Fun fact**: the slower motherboard clock is also more susceptible to [clock drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift) due to the larger quartz crystal. Of course, whether or not you want to delve into the depths of high-resolution timing all depends on how important timing is in your application. Happy coding!

Comment: Please read [Game Timing and Multicore Processors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which talks about `rdtsc`.

Comment: Thanks,   I'm using clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC... ) for my purpose.

Comment: I don't agree. The drivers that back QPF/QPC can use RDTSC just the same. On my machine, QPF returns 2.9 GHz, which is my CPU clock. QPC/QPF is just as effective but more portable than RDTSC, unless your system doesn't have drivers installed to use RDTSC as the QPC/QPF source.

Comment: For anyone reading in the year 2022 and beyond: QueryPerformanceCounter can be a very expensive call on some machines/configurations - several microseconds, vs several nanoseconds for rdtsc - and often has a resolution of only 1MHz, so it's not suitable for very high-resolution or very frequent time sampling, as you'd need for profiling high-performance applications like games. Hence why serious profiling tools use rdtsc for instrumentation on Windows. QueryPerformanceCounter is the appropriate tool for something like frame pacing, but not for profiling.

Comment: I should mention, the page @JesseGood linked is now very out of date - for example, it claims that rdtsc depends on clock frequency, which hasn't been true on any CPUs for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has introduced a new way of generating results for `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

This function is assumed to be of finest possible granularity but its accuracy has to be looked at: The value returned by `QueryPerformanceFrequency` is neither exactly what is observed nor is it a constant. Particulary older systems suffer from severe thermal drift.

I have written some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801813/c-usleep-is-obsolete-workarounds-for-windows-mingw/11470617#11470617).