# Sleeping for less than a millisecond in C++

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Sleep Less Than One Millisecond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85122/sleep-less-than-one-millisecond)

Is there a way to "sleep" for less than a millisecond in C++, but without a busy loop?

Comment: Why do you want to sleep? In my experience the best way to handle problems that involve sleeping is not to sleep in the first place.

Comment: **"sleep" for less than a millisecond in C++**. Then why should sleep?

Comment: I getting continuous input, but I need to sample it every 100 microseconds.

Comment: I guess you will need some sort of a real time OS in order to sleep less than a ms.

Comment: You're not going to achieve 100 microsecond timing on standard windows without a device driver. Preferably an RTOS.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a timer with much better resolution than that. I think busy loop is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Under Windows, even without sleeping you can't ensure that two consecutive instructions will be carried out with less than a millisecond between them.