# Timer: period less than a millisecond

Tags: java, timer

As the title, is there a way to get the Timer working under the threshold of a millisecond?

My question is similar the following one, but it is intended for Java:
[Thread.Sleep for less than 1 millisecond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254703/thread-sleep-for-less-than-1-millisecond)

Comment: You need to read this post http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/10/measuring-microsecond-in-java.html on this very subject.

Comment: check this answer for a workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35189397/4043486

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to sleep, `Thread.sleep` has 2 methods, [one of which accepts nanoseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29). If you want to schedule a task, you can use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which `schedule` methods can use nanoseconds too.

As explained by @MarkoTopolnik, the result will most likely not be precise to the nanosecond.

Comment: Thanks, I have used Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() and it worked

Comment: Source code of Thread.sleep(mills, nanos) shows just rounding up any nanos to 1 millicesond :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos)
```

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824110/accurate-sleep-for-java-on-windows) with details on issues with this on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could wait on an object that nobody will notify...

```
synchronized (someObjectNobodyWillNotify) {
    try {
        someObjectNobodyWillNotify.wait(0, nanosToSleep);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

(In this scenario, I'm guessing spurious wakeups are okay. If not, you need to record your `System.nanoTime()` at the start and wrap the `wait` in a loop that checks that enough time has elapsed.)

Answer (score 1):

The java.util.concurrent package uses [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#NANOSECONDS) for timing. TimeUnit has a NANOSECONDS field.