# Is it possible to sleep in granularity of microseconds in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, sleep

Is it possible to sleep in granularity of microseconds in linux kernel ?
From what i know, there is `msleep()` which can sleep in milliseconds
and there is `udelay()` which busy waits for time in microsecond
granularity.
But I need to sleep ( not busy wait ) for granularity of microseconds ...

Is there a way to code a new API in linux kernel to allow this ?

Comment: You may find the useful link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85122/sleep-less-than-one-millisecond and this question seems to be dublicated from http://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg1136365.html

Comment: Linux time-slices are on the order of 0.75 ms to 6 ms by default, so sleeping for less than that doesn't really make any sense. `udelay` will try to put the processor into a low-power mode anyway (which is basically what the idle task does regardless, so you aren't missing much).

Comment: int usleep(useconds_t usec);

Comment: I found seemingly useful information in http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-3 .

Comment: Why does it matter if you're busy-waiting or not? If you require/expect other processes to get CPU time when your process is busy, you are probably expecting a bit too much out of Linux' scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

If you need precision of less than a jiffy, hrtimers are your best bet. Enable High-resolution timer config in your kernel, you can use hrtimer APIs like hrtimer_nanosleep(basis for user-space posix nanosleep) that sleeps in nanosecs res

More ref here http://elinux.org/High_Resolution_Timers and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/hrtimers.txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The highest resolution wait can be achieved by using `ppoll` with no FDs and passing a `timespec` which is in nanoseconds. Note that `ppoll` will wait *at least* that amount of time - the underlying clock may be of worse granularity.