# Infinite loop crashes Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an incremental game (e.g. Cookie Clicker-style games) in Python, which is a still a work-in-progress.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

master = Tk()

n = int(0)
inc = int(1)
money = int(0)
autoclick = int(0)

def deduction(): # 1 autoclick is $20, deductions

    global money, autoclick

    money = money - 20
    autoclick = autoclick + 1
    automoney()

def automoney(): # Increases money every second

    global money, autoclick

    money = money + autoclick
    print("+" + str(autoclick) + " money!")
    time.sleep(1)
    automoney()

def printmoney(): # Checks how much money you have

    print('Your balance is ' + str(money) + ' dollars.')

def collectmoney(): # Increases money every click

    global n, inc, money

    n = n + inc
    print('+' + str(n) + ' money!')
    money = money + n
    n = n - inc

def checkauto(): # Checks how much Auto-Clickers you have

    global autoclick

    print('You have ' + str(autoclick) + ' Auto Clickers.')

button1 = Button(master, text='Cash!', command=collectmoney)
button1.pack()

checkbutton1 = Button(master, text='Check Cash', command=printmoney)
checkbutton1.pack()

incbutton1 = Button(master, text='Auto Clicker', command=deduction)
incbutton1.pack()

checkbutton2 = Button(master, text='Check Auto Clickers', command=checkauto)
checkbutton2.pack()

mainloop()
```

... it works, but Tkinter crashes when I press the button Auto Clicker (probably due to the infinite loop).

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388625/update-a-variable-every-second-in-python), and changed some of the code to this:

```
def automoney():

    money.set(money.get() + autoinc.get())
    incbutton1.after(1000, automoney)

incbutton1.after(1000, automoney)
incbutton1.mainloop()
```

... which didn't work.

Is there any way to fix the button crashing, while still doing everything it's meant to do?

Comment: @tobias_k I tried that, but it came up with the error that "incbutton1 is not defined".

Comment: @tobias_k Wait... it works! The Tkinter buttons no longer crash!

Comment: You do not need that last two lines. The function is called via the button, and you already had a `mainloop` in your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `time.sleep`, Tkinter does not crash, but the button does never "finish", and thus the UI remains unresponsive. Using `after` is correct, you just have to remove those two lines:

```
incbutton1.after(1000, automoney)
incbutton1.mainloop()
```

You do not need those, as the `automoney` function will be called when the button is clicked.

Also, you might want to change your `deduction` function so it does not call the `automoney` function again, if it is already running, but just increases the `autoclick` increment.

```
def deduction(): # 1 autoclick is $20, deductions
    global money, autoclick
    money = money - 20
    autoclick = autoclick + 1
    if autoclick == 1: # only start the first time
        automoney()

def automoney():
    global money, autoclick
    money = money + autoclick
    print("+" + str(autoclick) + " money!")
    master.after(1000, automoney)
```